# SQLAlchemy query multiple columns using a single query

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, web-development-server

I have a project where people can add books and others can rate it and comment on it. The relationship has been defined, but I cannot query the rating for a specific book and compute its sum. The tables have been defined as:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64))
    author = db.Column(db.String(64))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='book', lazy='dynamic')

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.id'))
```

People can rate the book and comment their views. However, I am not able to get the ratings of the book though normal queries

```
@main.route('/book/<int:book_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def book(book_id):
    book = Book.query.get(book_id)
    comments = Comment.query.filter_by(book_id=book_id).all()
    total_rating = book.comments.rating
```

**I want to fetch the ratings of the book in order to average and display it at once.**

Here is the error that I get:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBTEt.png)

I have tried to join the table in order to get a list of all the ratings that have been given. I want to get all the ratings of the book and then average it.